# How to change text color in a cell

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

So my boss sent me this spreadsheet with an Apps Script extension (I looked it up and it says JavaScript) I am no coder. It's supposed to auto send spreadsheet in email and show table (this part is working just fine).

My boss is trying to ask me if I could look at the html part and maybe I could change the "DONE" part of the text into green instead of black.

This is how it looks now

[image]

code.gs

```
var config = {
  // Google Sheet configuration
  googleSheet: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/asdfghjkl/edit",  // ID or Sheet URL
  sheetName: "email-schedule",
  tableRange: "B4:G9",   // Named Range OR Range i.e A6:B9

  // change backgroud color of table header row
  bgColor: "lightblue",

  //  Email Configuration
  toEmail: "momoiru97@gmail.com",
  cc: "", // comma separated email ids.
  subject: "Table from GoogleSheet",
  
  // Body text table
  body: `Hello,
  I am xxx.
  Link to file: xxx`,
  
  // Footer Signature after table
  signature: `Thank you,
    xxx`,
};


var isDate = function(date) {
  return (date instanceof Date);
}


function sendEmail() {
  // Function to send Email

  // get table data
  var tableData = getData();
  // get email template
  var htmlTemplate = getEmailTemplate(tableData);

  // Send Email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: config.toEmail,
    subject: config.subject,
    cc: config.cc,
    htmlBody: htmlTemplate
  });
  Logger.log(`Email send successfully to '${config.toEmail}'.`);
}

function getEmailTemplate(tableData) {
  // Function to Get Template for Email

  // Create GMail Template
  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTemplate');

  htmlTemplate.body = config.body;
  htmlTemplate.headers = tableData.headers;
  htmlTemplate.rows = tableData.rows;
  htmlTemplate.footer = config.signature;
  htmlTemplate.bgColor = config.bgColor;

  const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  // Logger.log(htmlForEmail);

  return htmlForEmail;
}

function getData() {
  // Function to Get Data

  // Open Sheet
  var gsheet;
  if (config.googleSheet.includes("docs.google.com")) {
    gsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(config.googleSheet);
  }
  else {
    gsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(config.googleSheet)
  }

  Logger.log("Your Google Sheet Name: " + gsheet.getName());
  Logger.log("Your Google Sheet URL: " + gsheet.getUrl());
  
  // var sheet = gsheet.getSheets()[0]; // Select by index
  var sheet = gsheet.getSheetByName(config.sheetName); // select by name
  Logger.log("Selected Sheet Name: " + sheet.getName())

  // Get Table
  var values = sheet.getRange(config.tableRange).getValues();
  var rows = values.slice(1);

  // Parse Data
  for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
    for (var j=0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
      const cell = rows[i][j];
      if (isDate(cell)) {
         Logger.log(cell);
         const options = {month: 'short' };
         rows[i][j] = `${cell.getDate()}-${cell.toLocaleString(undefined, options)}-${cell.getFullYear()}`;
      }
    }
  }

  // Store Data
  var tableData = {
    headers: values[0],
    rows: rows
  };

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(tableData));
  return tableData;
}
```

this is the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>

    * {
      font-family: Verdana sans-serif;
      font-size: 12pt;
    }
  
  table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size:15px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
}
tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

th, thead {
  background-color: <?= bgColor ?>;
}

.table-container, .footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Body -->
    <div>
      <pre><?= body ?></pre>
    </div>

    <!-- Table -->
    <div class="table-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <? headers.forEach(cell => {?>
            <th><?= cell ?></th>
          <?})?>
        </thead>

        <tbody >
          <? rows.forEach(row => {?>
            <tr> 
              <? row.forEach(cell => {?>
                <td style="text-align:center"><?= cell ?></td>
              <?})?>
            </tr>
          <?})?>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer">
      <pre><?= footer ?></pre>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried changing the `color:black` into `color:green` but it changes the whole texts' color.

```css
 table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size:15px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: green;
```

Wanted it to maybe look like if it's "DONE" then color should be "green". Wanted it to maybe look like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Ideally to should spend some time to learn the pretty basics of JavaScript and HTML as the change that you want to be done requires much more than what you have tried. You might find helpful to start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. To make the question a good fit for this site, you should make a more specific programming question rather than just passing a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line in `Code.gs`:

```
  var rows = values.slice(1);
```

...with:

```
  var rows = values.slice(1).map(row => row.map(value => value === 'Done' ? '<span style="color:green;">Done</span>' : value));;
```

And this line in `emailTemplate.html`:

```
                <td style="text-align:center"><?= cell ?></td>
```

...with:

```
                <td style="text-align:center"><?!= cell ?></td>
```